# Clojure: managing individual threads

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a simple function like so:

```
(defn process-files
  "Take file name and read data"
  [file]
   (let [data (slurp file)
        rows (rest (c/parse-csv data))]
        (doseq [row rows]
          (future (call-url (nth row 3 nil)))
    ))
```

It passes an ID into call-url, which then makes a call to a cgi script. The cgi script places a document into a queue, based on its ID, where it then waits for the processing to complete. For my purposes, the portion of the cgi call that waits for the process to complete is only of interest to someone hitting the service through a browser.

So what I'd like to do is kick off, say, 100 threads, wait long enough for the 'put document into queue' phase of the cgi script to run, then shut down those threads (instead of sitting there waiting to complete) and proceed to the next batch of 100 rows. Rinse and repeat.

(shutdown-agents) seems to act like system.exit in that it kills the whole program and even kills my repl.

(future-cancel) works on a single thread, but I'm not sure how to make it cancel a batch of threads.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that "waiting long enough for the 'put document into queue' phase of the cgi script to run" is a good idea. How can you define "long enough"? You might try to estimate how long it is and close or time out the HTTP request to the endpoint but what if the server running CGI script will be a bit slower?

In my opinion you should expose two separate endpoints in your CGI service:

- one that is exposed for the UI interface where the users will wait for the processing to complete
- a separate one that is designed to be "fire and forget" that you could use in your scenario

Such a design will make your processing reliable and will also make your client application much simpler (the threads will block and wait as long as needed and no longer so you don't need any workarounds for using existing endpoint in a way it wasn't designed for).

If you cannot or don't want modify your CGI endpoints I would use a timeout feature of HTTP client library. You could for example use `:socket-timeout` of [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#get) or `:timeout` parameter in [httpkit client](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html#combined) which works on the request level. I am not sure however if it will always work reliable as those timeouts work on the network level and any received byte will reset the timeout counter.

You might also use asynchronous client where you would block and wait for the response only 10 seconds and ignore the response. [For example using httpkit library](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html#sync):

```
(let [response-future (http/post "http://example.com/cgi-bin/abc")]
  (deref response-future 10000 :time-out))
```

`http/post` will call the server and return the future object which will contain the response. You can use [`deref`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) to block and wait for the response but no longer than provided timeout in msecs. If there will be no response within 10 seconds, `:time-out` value will be returned (you can just ignore the return value).

Comment: Typically the return portion of the cgi waits for a document to be converted to PDF and displays it in the browser. If that wait portion is exited, the backend process still escorts the converted document into a 'converted document' filer for consumption by end users, so I am not concerned with waiting for each document at the back end. I just want to hijack the push function and exit. It is a legacy system that we are migrating away from, so we are avoiding any unnecessary tinkering with existing code. The front-end is pretty predictable @ ~ 10 seconds per document. I am waiting 20.

Comment: I have added a possible solution using async http calls and timeouts.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider the approach you mentioned.